# Print help for both normal and positional args with boost::program_options

Tags: c++, boost, command-line-arguments, boost-program-options

When you use Boost library `program_options` it is very easy to print help for your program:

```
boost::program_options::variables_map options;
boost::program_options::options_description optionsDesc;
boost::program_options::positional_options_description positionalOptionsDesc;
//...
if(options.count("help"))
{
    cerr << optionsDesc << endl;
}
```

But how do you add the options from `positional_options_description` to the help message? In the tutorial I can see the output of such set-up, at the end of the section:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#id2607297

The option `input-file` is printed in help and it is positional. But I can't see the code.
Is there an build-in way to print it, like with `options_description` or you have to do it manually? Apparently the `<<` does not work for `positional_options_description`, the compilation error is:

```
error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
```

Comment: If it helps, you can find the full code [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/program_options/example/options_description.cpp).

Comment: Thanks llonesmiz, it indeed helped a lot! I though that I don't have to add positional args to `options_description` if I add them to `positional_options_description`, but you have to add to both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that streaming description only prints out the options. It does not print the name of the program or the actual description of what the program does. You should manually print any positional parameter you have as part of the output message:

Instead of

```
if (vm.count("help")) {
    cout << "Usage: options_description [options]\n";
    cout << desc;
    return 0;
}
```

You could easily say

```
if (vm.count("help")) {
    cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [options] <description of positional 1> <description of positional 2> ...\n";
    cout << desc;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As I said in the comment to the question I wasn't adding my positional arg to `options_description`, only to `positional_options_description`. That's why it didn't got printed. It normally does, so you're code does what I wanted, I just made mistake in the other place. I also agree it is nice to print the usage in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at boost::program_options::positional_options_description.name_for_position(i)

The error message is something unrelated, I forget what eactly something to do with cpp11

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do for automatically printing positional options:

```
void printUsage(const std::string &argv0)
{
    std::ostream &os = std::cout;

    os << "Usage:" << std::endl;

    // print only basename of argv[0]
    boost::filesystem::path p(argv0);
    os << "  " << p.filename().string();

    os << " [options]";

    std::string last = "";
    int rep = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < positional_options_description_.max_total_count(); i++)
    {
        const std::string &n = positional_options_description_.name_for_position(i);
        if(n == last)
        {
            if(!rep) os << " ...";
            if(rep++ > 1000) break;
        }
        else
        {
            os << " " << n;
            last = n;
            rep = 0;
        }
    }
    os << std::endl << std::endl;
    os << options_description_ << std::endl;
}
```

The logic for checking repeated argument names is needed only if you have repeated options that can repeat an infinite number of times, i.e. with count equal to -1, otherwise you can simplify this a little bit, e.g. replace the `if... else if ...` with `os << " " << n;`.

With current (1.68) version of boost, there is no way of telling if an option description is positional or not, so there is nothing to do to improve the help, for example, excluding positional options from being printed.